# Is there a way to change the order of pinned folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 8 users are able to drag and drop the order of pinned folders on the task bar, but I haven't be able to figure this out in Windows 10. It seems like we are stuck with the order that we pin them in.

Comment: I couldn't find a way of doing this either

Comment: Related question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/947505/how-do-i-rearrange-pinned-taskbar-items)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can adjust the order of the pinned folders by opening File Explorer with Win + E. The pinned items appear under Frequent Folders but also under "Quick Access" in the Navigation Pane on the left hand side. That's where you can drag them up or down.

Comment: You might want to clarify, the pinned folders in the taskbar mirror the Quick Access order. At first I thought you misunderstood the question

Comment: The suggested solution works for the pinned folders of File  Explorer.
However, I have Excel pinned to the taskbar and some frequently used workbooks pinned to it. I can't change the order there too.
Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @gordon613 AFAIK you cannot rearrange those items except by unpinning and re-pinning them. A real step back for Win10, this is.

Comment: Works just fine for me in Win10. Just make sure when you click and drag that you "let go" in the thin space between folders or else you will create a link in another folder. Also make you you are doing this in the Navigation Pane on the left hand side.

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to rearrange Quick Access after adding Libraries to it. After unpinning all of the libraries, I was able to rearrange items again.

[image: Screen shot of removing a library from Quick Access]

Comment: Thanks for this. I removed my Documents library and was able to re-order quick access items again. Strangely, even after adding the Documents library back I can still re-order items.

Answer (score 2):

I find I can rearrange by drag-and-drop to *some locations* of the Quick Access list, but not all.

I haven't figured out exactly how it works, but it's quite weird. Depending on how I rearrange, more or less slots become "available" for drag-and-drop.

Another item of arcane Windows knowledge to keep track of...

Comment: I've noticed that too.  It appears that some items can be rearranged, others can be rearranged but not on all positions, and others cannot be moved at all.  Plus, *which* item can be moved changes over time -- apparently it depends on the phase of the Moon.  My suggestion is to try rearranging them now and then until you reach the desired order.  Thanks Windows life isn't boring.